# Why is sometimes the wave function written as $\exp(i(\omega t-kz))$, so ωt and kz are switched?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Is it legitimate to write $-\exp(i(kz-\omega t))$ as $\exp(i(\omega t-kz))$?

Answer (score 3):

The statement:

$$ -exp(i(kz-wt)) = exp(i(wt-kz)) $$

is obviously false as you can prove very easily by expanding the equation using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

However they are both plane waves. So if you're studying some system where you're expanding solutions as linear combinations of plane waves then they are both valid ways to write down your plane waves.

Answer (score 1):

The sinusoidal plane wave solution of the wave equation is $u(z,t)=Acos(kz−ωt)$. Sometimes it is more convenient to write it in exponential notation: thus, both $u_1(z,t)=Aexp(i(ωt−kz))$ and $u_2(z,t)=exp(i(kz−ωt))$ are accepted, with the understanding that the true solution is to be intended as the real part of $u_1$ or $u_2$.

Answer (score 0):

A wave $$u(z,t) = \exp(i(\omega t-kz))$$ is a wave moving in the positive $z$ direction and $$u(z,t) = \exp(i(\omega t+kz))$$ in the negative $z$ direction. Since time always flows in the positive direction it makes sense to put it as the first argument since it looks better than $$u(z,t) = \exp(i(-kz+\omega t))$$